# How to extract data from many pages at the same time using python?

Tags: python, extract, text-extraction, data-extraction

I use python 3.6 , and I try to extract data from page but i want to extract the data from multiple page at the same time , the code as here :

```
   page = requests.get('http://www.poetsgate.com/ViewPoem.aspx?id=12343')
   tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
   text1 = tree.xpath('//div[@class="col1 first"]/text()')
   text2 = tree.xpath('//div[@class="col2 second"]/text()')
```

is there any way to extract the data, but I don't prefer to use a list of all URLs for the pages!

Comment: Without a list of URLs?  You could perform a recursive `wget`. I don't know how you're going to figure out which `?id=`s to use unless you have access to that website's database.

Answer (score 0):

Without more detail, I presume it's not possible without using a list of URLs (whether you make it by hand, or programmatically get them is another question ;).

I'd recommend a [helper function](https://web.cs.wpi.edu/~cs1101/a05/Docs/creating-helpers.html) to make working with a list [composable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition_(computer_science)):

```
url_list = ["http://example.com/route/page", ...]
for url in url_list:
    output = extract_data(url)
    do_something(output)

def extract_data(url):
   page = requests.get(url)
   tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
   text1 = tree.xpath('//div[@class="col1 first"]/text()')
   text2 = tree.xpath('//div[@class="col2 second"]/text()')
   return text1, text2
```

Comment: is there any way to get all URLs programmatically ?
for example , i want to extract the data from these URLs but i don't prefer to go in each URL to copy it and past in the list to do sth , 
http://www.poetsgate.com/Poet.aspx?id=45&type=cat&typeid=5

Comment: @RazanBalatiah That may be it's own question, but it's similar to what @alex suggested above. You can iterate through all the `?id=$i`, but I'm guess you'll run into a lot of garbage or 404s that way, so be prepared for it. Or keep track of the `?id=` links you find, and batch them all together. But I get the feeling you know what you want, and I don't understand why you can't use a list.